# if both $f$ and $g$ are measurable functions, is $f\cdot g$ measurable?

Tags: real-analysis

suppose $f$ and $g$ are two measurable functions on $\mathbb{R}^{d}$, is $f\cdot g$ measurable?
 I think the answer is yes. I tried to prove this proposition by writing $(f\cdot g)^{-1}([a,\infty])$ as the countable union of $f^{-1}((\frac{1}{n},\infty])\cap g^{-1}([an,\infty])$

Is my idea correct? thank you for any comment or improvement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f\cdot g = \frac{(f+g)^2-(f-g)^2}{4}$, so just prove that if $F(x)$ is measurable, then so is $F(x)^2$ and if $G(x)$ is measurable then so is $F(x)\pm G(x)$.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative solution: if $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ is a measure space, $S$ is a second countable topological space equipped with its Borel $\sigma$-algebra, then if $f,g:X \to S$ are measurable -- $f^{-1}(B) \in \Sigma$ whenever $B \subset S$ is Borel -- then $\psi:X \to S^2$ defined by $\psi(f(x), g(x))$ is measurable from $(X, \Sigma) \to (S^2, \mathcal{B}(S^2))$.  Now if $\phi:S^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then $\phi \circ \psi$ is measurable.  Your result (as well as sums, differences, and essentially every continuous operation you can do to real numbers) follows as a special case.

Answer (score 1):

$F^2$ is a measurable function and for $a\in R,\{x\in X:f(x)\le a\}=$null if $a<0$ and the same set is equal to $f^{-1}(-\sqrt{a},\sqrt{a}))4$

Note that $$f\cdot g=\frac12(f+g)^2-f^2-g^2)$$